# How to set a new different font while converting HTML to PDF using ITEXTRenderer

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert a HTML into a PDF. In HTML i have some symbols which are not showing up in PDF document. While debugging i found that &#8209 or &#x2011 character is not available in any of the default fonts available in the IText library. My HTML doesnt have Arial Unicode MS in its font family, and because of that even if i add that font to my itext renderer it doesnt work.So i am trying to find out during the creation a PDF can we do it with a font that is not mentioned in the HTML? 
Sample HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
    <title>Sample HTML</title>
    <body>
        <div style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:23px; color:#3F3F3F; font-weight:normal; ">Please call this 
            number in case of emergency,  123&#x2011;456&#x2011;7890.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java Code :

```
@Component
public class PDFConverter {

@Autowired
private Tidy tidy;

@Autowired
private ITextRenderer renderer;

@Autowired
private Gson gson;

public String pdfBox(byte[] bytes) {
    byte[] outDoc = null;
    String pdf = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String html = new String(bytes);
        String xhtml = toXHTML(html);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xhtml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ITextFontResolver  resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();
        Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(is, null);
        renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
        resolver.addFont("*filepath*/ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED); 
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        outDoc = outputStream.toByteArray();
        pdf = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outDoc);
        renderer.finishPDF();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return pdf;
}

private String toXHTML(String html) {
    final org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html, "UTF-8");
    document.outputSettings().syntax(org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
    document.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    document.outputSettings().charset("ASCII");
    document.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
    return document.html();
}
```

}

Comment: Your tags are confusing. Is your question about `iText`, about `FlyingSaucer`, or other `wkhtmltopdf`? You also need to add the version of the software you are using, and the piece of Java code you use to convert your HTML into PDF. Please edit your question.

Comment: If the question were about iText, the answer would be on this page: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml But something tells me that this isn't a question about iText, and that the wrong tag was chosen.

Comment: i have been using itextrenderer and flying saucer to do the conversion. During research i found out that there has to be some kind of unicode font ( Arial unicode) which is not mentioned in the HTML. So was looking for a way to embedded with a font that is not present in the HTML.

Comment: can any one help me with this